Intuition behind relation between Gamma and Standard Normal distribution
I read if $Z$ is a random variable with a standard Normal distribution and $X=Z^2$ then $X \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(1/2, 1/2)$.
I understand the math (manipulations of formulas) behind it.
What about the intuition?
How do I connect a $\operatorname{Gamma}(k, \lambda)$ distribution measuring the time until k-th event to what is measured by a random variable which is the square of a Normal?

Do you want intuition for Standard normal -> chi-squared or the
Gamma -> chi-squared part?

I'm interested in hearing both

I am filtering out this question

How do I connect a distribution measuring the time until k-th event to what is measured by a Normal?

More generally the sum of $n$ squared normal distributed values is gamma distributed
$$\sum_{k=1}^n Z_k^2 \sim \operatorname{Gamma }\left( \frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
Why does this relate to a waiting time distribution? It is because the time for some event can often be the sum of several individual independent times of intermediate steps.
For example, the sum of several geometric distributed variables is a negative binomial distributed variable and also often related to a waiting time.

The Gamma distribution* is a common case for waiting time distributions because it contains the special case of the exponential distribution $\Gamma(1,\lambda) \sim \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$, which has the memorylessness property.

One connection between the normal distribution and the exponential distribution is that they are both maximum entropy distributions**.

The normal distribution with the condition that variance is constrained (and the mean).
The exponential distribution with the condition that the mean is constrained.

The distribution of the sum of two squared normal distribution turns the constraint of the variance (for the variable that is to be squared) into a constraint for the mean (for the variable that is the result of the squaring).

*Often the simpler Erlang distribution is used.
The case of $$Z^2 \sim \Gamma(1/2,1/2)$$ is actually not so much related to a waiting time.
You do have the use of the gamma distribution as a generalisation of the Erlang distribution, and it has infinite divisibility, but the Erlang distribution is more common.
So the relationship with a waiting time is more strong for the sum of two squared normal distributed variables $$Z_1^2 + Z_2^2 \sim \operatorname{Erlang}(1,1/2) \sim \operatorname{Exp}(1/2)$$

** Note that these distributions are popular because maximum entropy happens (approximately) in many different situations. For example, a maximum entropy distribution for waiting times, like distance between events in a Poisson process.
